# Хочу заменить input на что-нибудь без дополнительной библиотеки. Как можно сделать? С библиотекой все работает, но нужно без него

Tags: c#

Часть кода. В интернете не смог найти что-либо.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYiwd.jpg]

Comment: Пожалуйста, публикуйте код текстом, а не картинкой! Не очень понятно, в чем именно проблема - в считывании из ввода, или в проверке, является ли считанное число `double`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном конкретном случае используется сторонний класс `Input` в котором есть метод `Check(**минимальное значение**, **максимальное значение**)`.
Есть два варианта:
1. Создать класс **Input** и реализовать в нем метод **Check**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    static class Input
    {
        public static double Check(double min, double max)
    {
        double inputValue;
        try
        {
            inputValue = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (inputValue < min)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Меньше заданного диапазона!");
                return 0;
            }
            else if (inputValue > max)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Больше заданного диапазноа");
                return 0;
            }
            else return inputValue;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Не является числом!");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите первое число последовательности");
            double a1 = Input.Check(double.MinValue, double.MaxValue);
            Console.Write("Введите второе число последовательности");
            double a2 = Input.Check(double.MinValue, double.MaxValue);
        }
    }
}
```

2. Заменить **Input.Check()** на **Console.ReadLine()**

   ```
   using System;

   namespace ConsoleApp1
   {
   static class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               Console.Write("Введите первое число последовательности");
               double a1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
               Console.Write("Введите второе число последовательности");
               double a2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
           }
       }
   }
   ```

P.S.: Понимаю, что оказываю медвежью услугу, но очень захотелось вспомнить консоль ;-)

Comment: Я так же сделал, заменил на консоль ридлайн. все окей) спасибо